# Is possible to insert an array inside another array in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, array

Let's say I have a table in postgresql called 'Test' which contains a single column called 'Column1' of the type int[]. So, it can contain an array of integers for each row, for example, {1,2,3}. I want to know if it is possible to insert an array of arrays in a table in postgresql, like {{1,2,3},{1,3,5},{9,10}} in a single cell of a table in postgresql? If so then what should be the datatype of the column, and how can we achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> create table test (id int [])
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into test values ( ARRAY [1,2,3] )
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into test values ( ARRAY [ARRAY [1,2,3],ARRAY [1,2,4],ARRAY [1,2,5]] )
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from test
> ```
>
> ```
> | id                        |
> | :------------------------ |
> | {1,2,3}                   |
> | {{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,2,5}} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c8ceb77d189fc5dc837addc7f3d36877)*

Really - multi-dimentional array is formed.

---

> I want to know if it is possible to insert an array of arrays in a table in postgresql, like {{1,2,3},{1,3,5},{9,10}} in a single cell of a table in postgresql?

No. 3rd element have 2 elements whereas first two have 3 elements. The error message

> ERROR:  multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions

will be produced.

But different dimensions in different records are allowed.